# Erlang: using include from the console?

Tags: erlang, module, include

The include [directive](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html) is usually used for a .hrl file at the top of an .erl file.

But, I would like to use include from the Erlang console directly.

I am trying to use some functions in a module.  I have compiled the erl file from the console.  But, the functions I want to use do not work without access to the hrl file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you really mean? The `-include` directive is a compiletime feature. If you have successfully compiled the file then any functions in it which need "things" from the include file will have them, the compiler checks this. So after compilation the functions will work without access to the include file. What is it that doesn't work? Which access is that you are lacking?

Comment: I am looking to install jsonerl which has an hrl file( http://github.com/lambder/jsonerl ).  Instead of writing a file and then compiling it, I would like to use the functions in the hrl fiel directly from the shell.

Answer (score 12):

"But, the functions I want to use do not work without access to the hrl file."

This can't be true, but from this I'll take a shot at guessing that you want access to records in the `hrl` file that you don't (normally) have in the shell.

If you do `rr(MODULE)` you will load all records defined in `MODULE`(including those defined in an include file included by `MODULE`).

Then you can do everything you need to from the shell.

(Another thing you may possibly want for testing is to add the line `-compile(export_all)` to your `erl` file. Ugly, but good sometimes for testing.)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the [`compile:file`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html#file-2) option? You can pass a list of modules to be included thus:

```
compile:file("myfile.erl", [{i, "/path/1/"}, {i, "/path/2/"}])
```

Comment: what does the first element of the tuple in the list represent .. i ?  I presume the second element could represent the path of the .hrl file...

Comment: The atom `i`, indicating that the second element is to be included.

Comment: thanks manoj... this probably works.  but for my use case, it doesn't seem to.  i am try to run this module from the erlang console  http://github.com/lambder/jsonerl

Comment: Can you post sample code? A small snippet that uses the hrl and I'll try to see if I can make it work here.

Comment: i do a clone of the project (with sudo git clone) then in the folder start erl as root.  then in first line I do( compile:file("jsonerl.erl", [{i, "jsonerl.hrl"}].  I get ok message.  Then I do rd(artist, artist, {name, year_of_birth, city, photo, movies}).  This creates the record and works.  I create the variable Artist as in the docs of the project.  Now I do a variable:  Json = jsonerl:record_to_json(artist, Artist).  That's when I get an error.

Comment: @Ted:  `jsonerl.erl` does not define `record_to_json`. Naturally it will give an error.

Comment: @Manoj:  Yes, you're absolutely right.  Hence, the effort to get jsonerl.hrl (which defines record_to_json) compiled and accessible...

Answer (score 3):

It's worth nothing that jsonerl.hrl doesn't contain any functions. It contains macros. As far as I know, macros are a compile-time-only construct in Erlang.

The easiest way to make them available would be to create a .erl file yourself that actually declares functions that are implemented in terms of the macro. Maybe something like this:

```
-module(jsonerl_helpers).
-include("jsonerl.hrl").

record_to_struct_f(RecordName, Record) ->
    ?record_to_struct(RecordName, Record).
```

... which, after you compile, you could call as:

```
jsonerl_helpers:record_to_struct_f(RecordName, Record)
```

I don't know why the author chose to implement those as macros; it seems odd, but I'm sure he had his reasons.